# Easiest way to slide to position (position absolute)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the easiest way to slide an element up and down which has an absolute position? I was thinking of using a **transform transition** with **translate** unless there's an easier way to add sliding transitions to position changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transition would be the easiest way I think (no files to add)

Or you can use jquery with `.animate` like this :

```
.('#yourId').animate({top:200},500);
```

Comment: That would be the easiest way but after reading http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/ I will go with translate

Comment: intersting article, I'll have to take a closer look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use CSS, I would recommend checking out https://daneden.me/animate/

The site will let you build a custom CSS solution with a lot of different animations. Its a pretty decent library. If you are looking to use jQuery, then using .animate would be the way to go, as chadocat suggested. :)